# jjwt create a memory leak

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jjwt

**I am using jjwt api, i had the same implementation with old version of libs and SpringBoot and its works well, but always when i stop my application i have this warn:**

```
2023-03-22 10:57:39.430  INFO 7316 --- \[on(7)-127.0.0.1\] inMXBeanRegistrar$SpringApplicationAdmin : Application shutdown requested.
2023-03-22 10:57:39.441  INFO 7316 --- \[on(7)-127.0.0.1\] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service \[Tomcat\]
2023-03-22 10:57:39.446  WARN 7316 --- \[on(7)-127.0.0.1\] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application \[ROOT\] appears to have started a thread named \[HikariPool-1 housekeeper\] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.base@17.0.5/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.base@17.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
java.base@17.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1672)
java.base@17.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
java.base@17.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
java.base@17.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
java.base@17.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1122)
java.base@17.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
2023-03-22 10:57:39.447  WARN 7316 --- \[on(7)-127.0.0.1\] o.a.c.
```

I am trying use jjwt api with this depedencies:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.cubo333</groupId>
    <artifactId>auth</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>auth</name>
    <description>Serviço auth</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
```

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

When I close my application i have the HeapDump

[heapDump in VisualVm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLJC6.png)

My Repository

```
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, UUID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Users> {

    boolean existsByUsername(String username);

    boolean existsByEmail(String email);

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = "roles", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH)
    Optional<Users> findByUsername(String username);

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = "roles", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH)
    Optional<Users> findById(UUID userID);
}
```

My UserDetails service

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Users userModel = usersRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found with username: " + username));
        return new UserDetailIsmpl(userModel);
    }

    public UserDetails loadUserByUserId(UUID userId) throws AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException {
        Users userModel = usersRepository.findById(userId).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found with userId: " + userId));
        return new UserDetailIsmpl(userModel);
    }
}
```

My authentication token filter

```
@Log4j2
public class AuthenticationTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    JwtProvider jwtProvider;
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwtStr = getTokenHeader(request);
            if (jwtStr != null && this.jwtProvider.validateJwt(jwtStr)) {
                String userId = this.jwtProvider.getSubjectJwt(jwtStr);
                UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUserId(UUID.fromString(userId));
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));  
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Cannot set user Authentication", e);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getTokenHeader(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return headerAuth.substring(7, headerAuth.length());
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

My  properties

```
server:
  port: 5000

spring:
  application:
    name: auth-user
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/authentication_service_db
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: root
    password: 
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
      jdbc:
        lob.non-contextual-creation: true
    properties: 
      hibernate:
        show_sql: true
```

Comment: Any reason for not using the built in JWT library Nimbus that is already included into spring security?

Comment: No! JWT library Nimbus is a better way?

Comment: At least the same, and why pull in something that already exists?

Comment: but, I wanna find the probem beacause any project that I running with my repository into my UserDetails Service give the same error. I rune Visual Vm and I found a heap Dump when I finalize my application.

Comment: What makes you think this is your jwt library... THe warning is about HikariCP which starts a background thread to monitor idle connections. Normally this is closed during shutdown, but in your app something is preventing that (or you aren't using Spring Boot in a proper way and work around the configuration or Spring in general).

Comment: At first I thought it was the JWT library, but now I'm not sure. I noticed that when I use my repository inside my UserDetailsService and close the application the alert happens.